# why vector in class automatically become NULL

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm creating simple cache model to simulate certain applications.

But, a problem happens in `lru` from below code. (I did not copy unrelated codes)

**main.cpp**

```
int main(void) {
  Cache* L1Cache = new Cache(64, 64, 8);
  Cache* L2Cache = new Cache(256, 64, 4);
  Cache* L3Cache = new Cache(2048, 64, 16); // This object causes problem
  Cache* L4Cache = new Cache(2048, 64, 8);

  L1Cache->initCache();
  L2Cache->initCache();
  L3Cache->initCache();
  L4Cache->initCache();
  return 0;
}
```

**Cache.h**

```
typedef struct CacheLine {
  std::vector<uint64_t> data;
}CacheLine;

typedef struct CacheSet {
  std::vector<bool> valid;
  std::vector<uint64_t> tag;
  std::vector<CacheLine> directory;
}CacheSet;

typedef struct LRU {
  std::vector<std::vector<bool>> lruMatrix;
}LRU;


class Cache {
public:
  Cache(uint32_t cacheSizeInKB, uint32_t lineSizeInByte, uint32_t numOfDirs) {
    // set cache size
    this->cacheSizeInKB = cacheSizeInKB;
    this->lineSizeInByte = lineSizeInByte;
    this->numOfDirs = numOfDirs;
    this->numOfSets = (cacheSizeInKB * 1024) / (lineSizeInByte * numOfDirs);

    // set memory address offset
    this->blockOffsetFrom = log2(lineSizeInByte) - 1;
    this->blockOffsetTo = 0;
    this->indexOffsetFrom = this->blockOffsetFrom + ceil(log2(this->numOfSets));
    this->indexOffsetTo = this->blockOffsetFrom + 1;
    this->tagOffsetFrom = 63;
    this->tagOffsetTo = this->indexOffsetFrom + 1;

    // reserve vectors before using
    cache.reserve(this->numOfSets);
    for (int x = 0; x < this->numOfSets; ++x) {
      cache[x].valid.reserve(numOfDirs);
      cache[x].tag.reserve(numOfDirs);
      cache[x].directory.reserve(numOfDirs);
      for (int y = 0; y < this->numOfDirs; ++ y) {
        cache[x].directory[y].data.reserve(lineSizeInByte / 8);
      }
    }

    lru.reserve(this->numOfSets);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->numOfSets; ++i) {
      lru[i].lruMatrix.reserve(numOfDirs);
      for (int j = 0; j < this->numOfDirs; ++j) {
        lru[i].lruMatrix[j].reserve(numOfDirs);
      }
    }

    std::cout << "1: " << &lru[0].lruMatrix[0] << std::endl;  // this shows correct memory address space
  }

  void initCache();
  void accessData(uint64_t addr);
  void printLRUMatrix(uint64_t index);

private:
  const uint32_t HIT = 1;
  const uint32_t MISS = 0;
  // cache size list
  uint32_t cacheSizeInKB;
  uint32_t lineSizeInByte;
  uint32_t numOfDirs;
  uint32_t numOfSets;

  // offset list
  uint64_t blockOffsetFrom;
  uint64_t blockOffsetTo;
  uint64_t indexOffsetFrom;
  uint64_t indexOffsetTo;
  uint64_t tagOffsetFrom;
  uint64_t tagOffsetTo;

  std::vector<CacheSet> cache;
  std::vector<LRU> lru;
};
```

Cache.cpp

```
void Cache::initCache() {
  for (int x = 0; x < numOfSets; ++x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfDirs; ++i) {
      cache[x].valid[i] = false;
      cache[x].tag[i] = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < numOfDirs; ++j)
          cache[x].directory[i].data[j] = 0;
    }
  }

  std::cout <<"2: " << &lru[0].lruMatrix[0] << std::endl; // This prints out 0 address in case of L3Cache
  /*
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfSets; ++i) {
    std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfDirs; ++j) {
      std::cout << "j: " << j << std::endl;
      for (int k = 0; k < numOfDirs; ++k) {
        std::cout << "k: " << k << std::endl;
        this->lru[i].lruMatrix[j][k] = false;

      }
    }
  }
  */
}
```

Output

```
1: 0x9464d0
1: 0x9f5190
1: 0xded230
1: 0x140d2d0
2: 0x9464d0
2: 0x9f5190
2: 0
2: 0x140d2d0
```

I'm facing strange situations from above code.

In case of L3Cache, the address of lru[0].lruMatrix[0] is different between Cache `constructor`(0xded230) and member function `initCache()`(0).

However, Other cases such as L1Cache, L2Cache, L4Cache prints correct(same) address between `constructor` and `initCache()`.

The only difference is that L3Cache uses **numOfDir 16** which is larger than others.

I couldn't figure out why this happens. It seems that there is no mistake in my code.

Are there any problems?

Comment: `cache.reserve(...)` changes the vector's capacity, not size. Its size is still zero. `cache[x]` then exhibits undefined behavior, for any value of `x`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can't understand why does it matters. Only L3Cache object causes the problem

Comment: "Undefined behavior" doesn't mean "something bad will happen". It means "something bad might happen". And it might not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading `lru` out of bounds.

Assuming nothing else touches `Cache::lru` before `Cache::initCache()` runs, this `std::vector` will initialize itself in an empty state by default. Since nothing in that function increases the size of `lru`, it's still empty when you hit this line:

```
std::cout <<"2: " << &lru[0].lruMatrix[0] << std::endl;
```

Inside of which, you have `lru[0]`. This is dereferencing the first element of `lru`, which does not exist. This is **Undefined Behavior**. *Anything* can happen. Don't do it. You need to make sure that something exists at position `0` before you dereference it.

The reason that the address of the vector at `lru[0].lruMatrix` appears to be zero is probably because the `vector` initially sets its dynamically allocated pointer to an array to be the null pointer. Thus, dereferencing the first element is dereferencing the null pointer. This is an implementation detail of your particular standard library vendor; do not rely on this behavior.

---

I also see the following pattern in your code:

```
lru.reserve(this->numOfSets);
for (int i = 0; i < this->numOfSets; ++i) {
    lru[i].doSomething();
    ...
```

This is Undefined Behavior for the same reason. [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) *does not change the size of the vector*. It only allocates storage. You probably want [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)